# How can I detect the user sign up event from Azure API Management?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

I've been using Azure API Management recently, and I would like to know if there is a way to detect the sign up process performed from the included Developer Portal.
Basically I need to be able to get the user unique id, to be able to map data stored in a database.
Is configuring Delegation the only way to capture this event?

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable the Resource Logs, it includes the `userId`.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-use-azure-monitor#resource-logs

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I did not see anytihng in the logs when creating the user, so I ended up implementing delegation.